# Get the coordinate of alignment pattern with ZXing

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I am using Zxing library for my android project.I am scaning qr code via Intent.I can get QR code contents. But I don't know how to get its alignment pattern positions which are the smaller square patterns found in all but the simplest QR Codes. How can i access it?  Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple way to get the e corners coordinates:

```
private Result readQRCode(BufferedImage bi){
    BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap;
    Result result;
    try{
        binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap( new HybridBinarizer(new BufferedImageLuminanceSource( bi )));
        result = new QRCodeReader().decode(binaryBitmap);        
        return result;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }                
}
```

The `result.getResultPoints()` contains 3 points, that are the tree main corners. So, you can do:

```
//position of reference
posX = result.getResultPoints()[1].getX();
posY = result.getResultPoints()[1].getY();
```

That's it!

Comment: I am new in android and trying this with https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-qr-code-scanner-tutorial/ 
Inside onActivityResult(), IntentResult does not have any method like getResultPoints(). 
Thank you for your help in advance.